# Django REST Framework custom permission causes JSON Parse error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following classes:

```
class SimpleArtistTrackSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArtistTrack
        fields = (...fields...)


class ArtistProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tracks = SimpleArtistTrackSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ArtistProfile
        fields = (..fields...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_or_explode(self.context)
        profile = ArtistProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        profile.owners.add(user)


class IsAnOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return True


class ArtistProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ArtistProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAnOwnerOrReadOnly]
```

Just by adding this permission class, all my requests now return a Parse error:

```
{"detail":"JSON parse error - Extra data: line 1 column 19 (char 18)"}
```

Debugging shows that the object permission method is running. Using a standard DRF IsAuthenticated permission does not cause this error, and removing the permission_classes gets rid of this error. For some reason, using the custom BasePermission seems to be causing.

Am I missing something? How can I debug this better to find the problem?

Comment: Can you add the JSON you post?

Comment: Could you also provide the traceback ?

Comment: All I get back is "{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}", I don't see a traceback. Some advice on how to find it would be helpful! (I'm a Django newb).

Comment: Here is the JSON I am posting: 

{
    "name": "Adelo43",
    "hometown_city": "St Louis",
    "hometown_state": "MO",
    "biography": "Yay",
    "website_url": "http://www.facebook.com/adelosband",
    "facebook_url": "http://www.facebook.com/adelosband",
    "twitter_url": "http://www.facebook.com/adelosband",
    "bandcamp_url": "http://www.facebook.com/adelosband"
}

Comment: I see several semicolons in the json (e.g. after the URLs) Can you verify that is the actual json you are posting?  And also, in `create` I think you can just use `self.request.user` rather than this `_explode` function.  Not sure if the `char 18` reference is to ascii 18 or not, but possibly points to malformed data as well.

Comment: The semicolons aren't in there, i don't know why SO formatted it like that.

Also, the _explode function I'm using gets the request user or throws an exception.